# Canvas - Make a circle in canvas move down in particular time

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'd like to create a circle `ctx.arc(10, 10, 15, 0, Math.PI*2, true);`  and hence make it flow downwards without losing its traces..
You can see this clearly in the below image -

[image]

Here as we can see on the dark side...the circle is actually moving as time passes.. I want to control the speed by entering the time...like from top to bottom it should reach in 2 seconds (or some other way to control its speed of flow)

EDIT:  Sorry for some buddies the question is: whats the most efficient and "NON-memory-hogging" method to do this, (I know there is this loop method but its very memory hogging method)

Comment: @Howard Here you go buddy, updated the question

Comment: What do you mean by "this loop method" and why do you think it is "memory hogging"? Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript knows `setTimeout(fn, ms)`, which is going to call the given function after the given number of milliseconds. However, the browser will need some time to render your drawings, and when you want the 2 seconds to be exakt you will have to watch about your frames/seconds rate.

Theres also a new [specification draft](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/RequestAnimationFrame/Overview.html) called `requestAnimationFrame`, see http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the top semicircle, a rectangle, and the bottom semicircle. You can calculate how much it should be moved down at a particular moment in time with:

```
(Date.now() - startTime) / t * (y2 - y1)
```

where `t` is the time it should take for the complete movement.

http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/231/.

```
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');

var y1 = 100,  // start y
    y2 = 300,  // end y
    x  = 200,  // x
    r  = 50,   // radius
    t  = 2000; // time

var dy = y2 - y1, // difference in y
    pi = Math.PI,
    startTime = Date.now();

var f = function() {
    var y = y1 + (Date.now() - startTime) / t * dy;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y1, r, pi, 0); // top semicircle
    ctx.rect(x - r, y1, r * 2, y - y1); // rectangle
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, -pi); // bottom semicircle
    ctx.fill();

    if(y < y2) { // if should be moved further
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame(f);
    }
};

f();
```

Comment: Please use [this shim](http://jsfiddle.net/paul/rjbGw/3/), not everyone uses webkit.